# Moving data between similar databases

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, database-migration

I have 2 SQL Server databases with almost identical structure. I have to regularly move data and only data from one to the other. The solutions found deal mostly with recreating the databases, I only want to move slightly modified data. The tables affected need to be configurable and the two databases are on different machines.

So: get data every minute or so, insert it into another one with very light, predefined changes and delete the original records.

What is the best solution in this situation for .NET and/or SQL? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "almost identical structure"?  Are these databases schemas built using the same scripts?  Also, what do you mean by only wanting to move "slightly modified data"?  Do you mean any rows that have been updated in a given time frame?

Comment: I think you are after [SQL Server Replication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx) but not sure what you mean by *"the two databases are on different machines"*

Comment: @mat By almost identical I mean that out of several dozens of tables a few have different relations. By "slightly modified data" things like setting a current date or no moving a specific column. They are simple modifications all and all.

Comment: @huMpty duMpty by "the two databases are on different machines" I mean to exclude solutions that use the same sql server instance. Just to state that we are talking of databases that are on physically separate computers.

Comment: @Custos: Are trying to do this on `localhost`?? These database should be in `servers`!!

Comment: @huMptyduMpty They are on different servers. So 2 different servers running two different instances of SQL Servers one having the database I intend to mode data from and the other I intend to move data to.

Comment: @Custos: So then what is the issue with using replication?

Comment: @huMptyduMpty In essence nothing, I don't know it yet(I am reading up). I was just answering your questions in case it changes your recommendation. :)

Comment: @Custos: All good then! get on with it.. good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use [SQL Server Replication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx). Using the in-built replication will prevent anyone reinventing the wheel.

Comment: As far as I know, replication does not delete the original records.  That was part of the requirements?

Answer (score 1):

May be you need a mirrored database. here there are a link that could you interest: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189047(v=sql.105).aspx

Another solution is more rudimentary, every table in your database should have a Timestamp field, then, through a .net application you select the rows depending of the timestamp and insert to to the other database.

Comment: To my knowledge for mirroring you need the same structure, which is not the case here, it is slightly different.
Since I move the data as in read-copy-delete I know what the new data is because everything in the first one is new data. I was looking for an already implemented solution so I don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

A **SSIS package** can be created to do the following in a restart-able manor.

1 - Mark the data you want to copy from Server A.

2 - Copy the data from Server A to Server B.

3 - Delete the marked data from Server A.

Nice thing about this solution is that the data sources can be virtually anything ODBC compliant.

I have written a Data Scoop **TSQL program** in the past that moved data from one database to another on the same server.  It was scheduled as a job to run every 5 minutes.

It used the OUTPUT clause to make the transaction one unit.  I also did it in a while loop using the TOP(N) clause so that the log file would not grow.

```
-- Delete a row and data to audit table
DELETE FROM [Person].[CountryByContinent]
  OUTPUT 'DELETE RECORD', DELETED.Country, DELETED.Continent
  INTO [Stage].[Audit] ([Action], [Country], [Continent])
WHERE [Country] = 'Chillis Grill & Bar'; 
GO
```

If it is on another server, you can always use a linked server.  However, they are know to be slow sometimes given the LAN/WAN transit.

Good luck in your endeavor.